# Sum of column in Python

Tags: python

I would like a code to create a bar chart that displays the sum of the total number of orders per year.

My data available are as follows: A column with the order number (ORDERNUMBER), a column with the corresponding year of the order (YEAR_ID). How to display the sum of the number of orders, for each year ?

Thanks, for helping

```
mydata = pd.read_csv('/sales_data.csv')
mydata.set_index("ORDERNUMBER", inplace = True)
mydata
df1=pd.DataFrame(mydata, columns =[‘QUANTITYORDERED’,’ORDERDATE’])
df1.hist()
plt.show()
```

For the moment I just have the 2 columns, but I don't know how to sum the number of orders with the criterion of the year in order to display figures with total for each year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you a table which shows the sum and mean order numbers per year, based on some random data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ORDERNUMBER', 'YEAR_ID'])
df['ORDERNUMBER'] = [1,2,3]*10
df['YEAR_ID'] = [2000, 2001, 2030] * 10

df.groupby(by='YEAR_ID').agg([np.sum, np.mean])
```